# list items to fade in and out one by one with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, list

I have a set of list items, and I need them to fade out and (the next one) fade in seamlessly. Here is my (not working) code:

```
    document.ready(function(){

        var list_slideshow = $("#site_slideshow_inner_text");
        list_slideshow.children("li:not(:first)").hide();
        // here begins the function
        function changeList(){
        var list_slideshow = $("#site_slideshow_inner_text");       
        var length = 0;
            if(list_slideshow.length === length)
            {
                list_slideshow.children("li").eq(0).fadeOut(300, function()  
                            {
                $(this).next().fadeIn(300);
                });
            }
        }
        setTimeout(changeList(), 500);
});
```

Comment: Which part doesn't work?

Comment: if this is all your code, its missing the `$(` at the beginning...

Comment: `var list_slideshow` is global variable to your function `changeList`, you dont need to define it again inside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your function:

1. You referenced the `setTimeout` function incorrectly (use `changelist` instead of `changelist()`).
2. `setTimeout` only calls once, so use `setInterval` instead.
3. You called the document ready function incorrectly (use `$(document).ready(function () {` or simply `$(function () {`
4. Your logic in the changeList function was wrong (e.g., `list_slideshow.length === length` will always be false).

The following code loops through list items as I think you intend (although you might want to alter the timings as you see fit):

```
$(function () {
    var list_slideshow = $("#site_slideshow_inner_text"),
        listItems = list_slideshow.children('li'),
        listLen = listItems.length,
        i = 0,
        changeList = function () {
            listItems.eq(i).fadeOut(300, function () {
                i += 1;
                if (i === listLen) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                listItems.eq(i).fadeIn(300);
            });
        };
    listItems.not(':first').hide();
    setInterval(changeList, 1000);
});
```

[See a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6kp3/)

Comment: Yes, and no.  There is obviously more wrong with this code, and I am working on a fiddle to fix all the issues.  But the setTimeout and the document.ready were two big obvious fixes.  Give me 5 minutes and I'll have a more complete answer with fiddle.

Comment: thanks all of you. Document.ready was correct just when copying I missed it.
I'm too new to jQuery that's why the code seems foolish. @Derek Henderson your code worked, thanks a lot, but I just add a line to exclude all the list items but the first one. because once in a while all the list items all together displayed, and then one by one were dropped hidden (there wasn't a seamless process). I added this line:
$("#site_slideshow_inner_text").children("li:not(:first)");